# Cannot pipeline EVALSHA commands in Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I'm attempting to pipeline the EVALSHA command of Redis inside Spring Data Redis as [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#pipeline).

However when I attempt to do this using `EVALSHA` it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` as found [here in the Spring Data Redis code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisScriptingCommands.java#L155).

Given that Redis itself [supports this](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining#pipelining-vs-scripting):

> Sometimes the application may also want to send EVAL or EVALSHA commands in a pipeline. This is entirely possible and Redis explicitly supports it

and Jedis also [supports this](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#pipelining) how come Spring Data Redis prevents it from happening? Is this just a feature that's not yet implemented or is this unsupported because it's not feasible for some reason? If so what's the alternative approach for pipelining scripts in Spring Data Redis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the details of spring boot, but you could possible create a new script that invokes all of your pipelined commands as a single script. For this to work, you'd need to concatenate all of your scripts into a single script and combine your data so that everything can be executed in the way you need it.

Comment: That's a possibility, however my scripts are already at the most transactional/atomic level in terms of each operation. I was hoping to use pipelining to apply a similar approach as Nagle's algorithm does in TCP but at the Redis layer where I just bulk together many scripts evals and push them together if the TCP socket is congested.

Comment: Well, if spring data redis doesn't support pipelining, you either need to use a new library, or try a trick like I suggested.

Comment: Yes using an alternative library is a solution (if somewhat obvious) and it's indeed what I've done - however the question is specifically why does Spring Data Redis not support pipelining of EVALSHA commands given both the underlying library (Jedis) and Redis itself is capable of doing this.